# Rails v3 session destroy doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-variables

I am obviously new to Rails, so I followed some examples on how to cleanup session on logout, but the session is not being cleaned up. See code here, first logger statement prints "20" and the second logger statement also prints "20"

Is there anything else i need to do, some configuration may be?? I tried session.delete(:user_id) as well & it just wont work.

```
def destroy
  logger.error "Session user #{session[:user_id]}" #prints 20

  session[:user_id] = nil
  session.delete(:user_id)
  session.destroy

  logger.error "Session user #{session[:user_id]}" #prints 20 again??

  redirect_to :root
end
```

**My environment** -

- Rails v3.0.3 Local Dev env (OSX)
- Everything is default since its a dev environment
- default session store, i haven't played around with that as yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of session.destroy use

> reset_session

This will reset all the sessions present in the application.

Thanks....

Comment: thanks, that worked. Just curious, why doesn't session.destroy work & what is the recommended way to wipe out of a session object?

Comment: hang on, you said - "reset all the sessions present in the application" does that mean it will reset the session object of all the users signed in the app?? thats not what i want, i only want to destroy the session of a particular who clicks sign-out.